# How to execute "SQL task" SSIS from file with utf8 encoding?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have some converter-program that prepares big sql file with insert statements like

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, ...) values
(val1, val2, ...)
(val1, val2, ...)
```

File has UTF8 encoding and can't be converted to some kind of ASCII because of different languages in it.

When I try to use this file as a sourse for "SQL task" I get an error (while executing package on SQL-server):

```
Error: The identifier that starts with 'Р—Р°РєСѓРїРѕС‡РЅР°СЏРџСЂРѕС†РµРґСѓСЂР°РЈСЃР»СѓРіРёРљРѕРЅСЃР°Р»С‚РёРЅРіРѕРІС‹С…РРЎРїРµС†РёР°Р»РёР·РёСЂРѕРІР°РЅРЅС‹С…РћСЂРіР°РЅРё' is too long. Maximum length is 128.
```

I try to use parameter CodePage=65001 in "SQL task" properties, but it doesn't help.

How can I run big SQL UTF8 file with a lot of inserts by SSIS?

Comment: Why are you using such a file in the first place? This is the slowest way possible. Importing a flat file with SSIS would be a **lot** faster - essentially a single, minimally-logged,  `BULK INSERT` operation instead of 100K individual INSERT statements

Comment: In any case, you don't need SSIS to execute a SQL script, you can use `sqlcmd`. Not that it will be faster. That's still 100K INSERTs, 100K transactions, 100K transaction log entries.

Comment: BTW unless that file uses the `N` prefix for string values, it will result in mangled text even if you opened it in SSMS with no UTF8 issues. In SQL Server, Unicode string literals use the `N` prefix. Anything else is considered ASCII (or whatever the collation is)

Comment: I agree - try sqlcmd with the -f option https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: The real solution is to use a flat file. `sqlcmd` is the quick fix until a proper CSV is produced

Comment: Yes, sqlcmd  works fine in my case, thank you!